# PHPExcel not reading user defined date formats

Tags: php, phpexcel

Trying to parse excel sheets but running into issues with user-defined date formats. The date format does not get added to the formattedData. I have no way of knowing what cell is going to contain a date and the dates come in all types of formats.

Example: M/D/YYYY - 11/17/2015

After parsing the sheet I get the floating point date with no format. I did not echo out the format from PHPExcel on this one.

In another case I echoed out the get format data and it was General for the column column that contained the date, but in excel it had a valid date format albeit user defined of D-MMM-YY - 15-Jul-14.

Testing for dates in these scenarios did not work either using,

PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell);

So to the question, how do I get the date format or test if it is a date when the format is user defined?

Comment: Are you reading this file with `readDataOnly` set to true? If so, then you're explicitly telling PHPExcel not to read the formatting at all, but simply to read only the raw data

Comment: readDataOnly is set to false.

Comment: What format is this file that you're loading? Because if it's a valid spreadsheet file, then you've identified yet another way of breaking PHPExcel that I can't even begin to guess at.... format should always be read unless its explicitly suppressed.... is it possible for you to send me a copy of this file so that I can try and figure out what's wrong?

Comment: And this has nothing to do with user-defined formats..... there's no difference between user-defined and Excel-defined as far as reading the file is concerned

Comment: It has been sent, let me know if you do not receive it

Comment: Mark, just wanted to verify you received the email.

Comment: Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue as [PHPExcel number formats for dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623488/phpexcel-number-formats-for-dates)

It is using built-in number format id's for custom date formats.